# Android iconify view correctly size of icons

Tags: android

i'm trying to use this awesome library, but after using and testing that. my icons size are very small and i dont know why dont show in 5 size and correctly size in difference screen size. for example this is my test:

```
<IconTextView
    android:id="@+id/imgv_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_animate_click_action"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_search"
    android:text="{fa-list-alt}"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

[image]

**ICONIFY Description:**

If, like me, you're tired of copying 5 images (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) for each icon you want to use in your app, for each color you want to use them with, and bang your head on the wall when you suddently need to change their color or size, then I think Iconify can help you.

sample of this library:

```
<IconTextView
    android:text="{fa-android}"
    android:shadowColor="#22000000"
    android:shadowDx="3"
    android:shadowDy="3"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:textSize="90dp"
    android:textColor="#FF33B5E5"
    ... />
```

Comment: Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

**General:**

That how things work in android when you set `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` as `wrap_content`

It depend on the screen resolution. so when those set as wrap content the images will be resized to prevent pixelation.

So, depending on screen resolution which changes from device to another. the icon will be small on one device and large on the other.

> Solution: provide multiple images each with different resolution for
>   different screen resolutions available by adding them to the drawable folders.

Otherwise, you can simply set with and height as match_parent or constant size as 40p for example. but, that does not guarantee that images will not be pixelized.

**Answer:**

You set width and height as wrap_content. there is no way that any library know what you really want. so simply set width and height to a constant value or set it as match_parent. tell me the results.

Also, try to remove the padding. maybe this library is adding a padding by itself.

Comment: did you try to set a specific value for the width and height? I think thats how this library works. what happen when you increase this value. does the icon gets bigger? if yes. that's it you succeeded.

Comment: yes sir i'm try to set directly size such as `android:layout_width="50dp" layout_height="50dp"` but that doesnt work and icon size dont change. are you try to use this library sir?

Comment: maybe tomorrow I will try. I go home now :)

Comment: if your are try to test it please help me to resolve this problem. thanks